# Replace whole Google Spreadsheet with CSV file via API

Tags: api, google-sheets, export-to-csv

Is there a **simple** way to replace the whole Google Spreadsheet data with CSV file **preserving style and conditional formatting** with API call?

Answer (score 0):

The `csv` file type **does not** keep the formatting of the cells in the sheet - hence the name `comma separated values`.

If you want to replace a Spreadsheet with its corresponding CSV file, you can use the Drive API to download the file as a `CSV`. A helpful explanation can be found in this article [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads).

Afterwards, you can upload the new file using the `Drive API` and remove the original Sheet.

- Upload the `CSV` file

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media
```

- Remove the sheet

```
DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId
```

#### Note

Also please bear in mind that when you export a Spreadsheet to CSV, only the [first sheet](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats) of it is `CSV`.

#### Reference

- [Download a file - Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads);
- [Upload a file - Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads);
- [Remove a file - Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete).